# Why is Dask is instantiating my class on submitting?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, dask

`process` is a function in my code that is passed to `client.submit`. All arguments passed after it should not be modified until they are passed to `process`.

However when I run the below code, `TestClass` type gets instantiated before being passed to `process` and 4 gets passed to init.

**Why is that and how can it be fixed?** I have not seen anything in the docs that guides me on this.

Full code:

```
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask.distributed import LocalCluster



class TestClass():

    def __init__(self, i):
        print('_________initiated___________') # this line should not be called b4 process runs
        print(i)
        pass

def process(c):

    print('-----------------')
    print(type(c)) # c should be type and not class '__main__.TestClass'
    return isinstance(c, tuple)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=4)
    client = Client(cluster)
    r = client.submit(process, (TestClass, 4) )

    r.result()
```

Comment: [client.submit](https://distributed.dask.org/en/latest/api.html#distributed.Client.submit) is for submitting a function to the scheduler which will be called on a worker. If you submit your class, it will be instantiated. What do you want to do?

Comment: `process` is the function to be run on a worker. TestClass is an argument to be passed to that function without being instantiated

Comment: Right read too fast. It's interesting, not sure why it happens - consider raising an issue on GH for clarification if no one answers here. As to how it can be "fixed", just use kwargs if possible. Calling ` client.submit(process, c=(TestClass, 4) )` returns your desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to your problem is simple: use a list instead of a tuple. Dask uses tuples to encode func-and-args in some cases, and it seems you are triggering that logic here.

```
r = client.submit(process, [TestClass, 4] )
```

does what you want. Obviously your function may need slight modification to deal with a list.